# Spring cloud bus - rabbitmq unavailability marks the instance DOWN

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I use spring cloud config bus (rabbitmq) in my micro-service. Only purpose for me to use rabbitmq in my microservice is spring cloud bus... I have 2 questions below.

1. When I was experimenting, I found that spring expects rabbitmq to be UP and running during application start. Which is contrary to what Spring cloud evangelises... (Circuit breakers...) To be fair, even service discovery is not expected to be up and running before starting an application. Is there any sensible reason behind this...?
2. Say, I start my application when rabbitmq is up and running. For some reason, rabbitmq goes down... What I should be losing is just my ability to work with rabbitmq... instead, /health endpoint responds back as DOWN for my micro-service. Any eureka instance listening to heart beats from my micro-service is also marking the instance as down. Any reasons for doing this...?

To my knowledge, this is against the circuit breaker pattern that spring cloud has evangelised.

I personally feel that spring cloud config bus is not an important feature to mark an application as down...

Is there any alternatives to tell my spring boot micro-service that connection to rabbitmq is not a critical service?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version are you using? That's one of the reasons that `eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled` is not enabled by default. You can turn off the rabbit health check. Part of the problem is we don't know if rabbit is only used by the bus or the application as well.

Comment: @spencergibb - Thanks for your response! We are using following versions... spring-boot = '1.4.0.RELEASE'; spring-cloud = 'Brixton.SR4' and you are correct in assuming that we use `eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled`. Any resources that I can refer to disable rabbit health check alone...?